# MATLAB printing out time as a string

Tags: string, matlab, time

What is the most efficient way to print out time as HH:MM:SS?

I have it set up where my time is x seconds. Then I calculate the hours, minutes, and left over seconds associated with the x seconds.

Then when I want to print it out as a string onto a figure, I do:

```
sprintf('Time: %d:%d:%d', hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Unfortunately, this looks ugly as if I have hours or minutes equal to 0, I get something like 0:0:23.

I suppose I can change the hours, minutes, seconds to a string before doing the sprintf. Is there a more efficient MATLAB way though? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best option for date formatting is [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html), for example:

```
 datestr(now, 'HH:MM:SS')
```

When it comes to `sprintf`, then have a look at the [formatting parameters](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html). You'll get a better result with zero-padding:

```
 sprintf('Time: %02d:%02d:%02d', hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: Great and thorough answer! Thank you!

Comment: Note that `datestr` is no longer recommended by the docs, which say you should instead use `datetime`. For example, use `datetime("now", Format = "HH:mm:ss")` (note the `mm` instead of `MM`.) However, for _converting a duration of seconds_, it's better to use `duration`, as detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your goal of formatting a given number of seconds to a nicely formatted string, you should probably use [`duration`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html), available since MATLAB R2014b:

```matlab
>> seconds = 5818956;
>> sprintf("Time: %s", duration(0, 0, seconds, Format = "hh:mm:ss"))

ans = 

    "Time: 1616:22:36"
```

(The two `0` arguments are the number of hours and minutes, respectively.)

---

There is also the special [`seconds`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.seconds.html) function to create a `duration` from only a number of seconds, but then you would need another two lines to set the `Format` and then print the formatted time.